# Anonymous functions using Anonymous functions

Tags: php, function, anonymous

im getting this error `Parse error: parse error`  when using this function,

```
 $rows_tick = array_filter(
                $rows, 
                function ($element) use ($date_tick) { 
                    return ($element['ModTime'] <= $date_tick->format("His000"));
                }
               );
```

am i miss some thing?

when using wampp server with php v 5.3.x it run normaly, but not when using xampp with php 5.2.9,

is it wrong ? when using Anonymous functions in php less than 5.3 ?

Comment: so sorry, i'm newbe in php, i just got this problem, :( but thanks all for the answer, i just wanna make sure, thats all, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous functions comes from php 5.3.

You should write normal function where php < 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> PHP version 5.3.0 Anonymous functions become available